# Devise in rails don´t display de view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using devise for logging user in rails.

When I try to create a new user I complete the form of new user, and when I click to save obtain this error.

```
Missing template users/registrations/create, users/registrations/create, devise/registrations/create, devise/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:es], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
```

and my route is this

```
  devise_for :users, :path=>"account", :controllers => {:sessions => "users/sessions", :registrations => "users/registrations"} do
    get "/", :to => "users/sessions#new"
  end
```

any idea!

Comment: What's in your custom `Users::RegistrationsController`? Could you paste it?

Comment: thanks @uDaY but actually I have the view in the devise archive, inside my archive view I have other archive call devise inside this I have confirmations, mailer..etc archive. Inside registration I have edit.html.haml and new.html.haml